# Scheme recursion start from beginning of the list after it's empty

Tags: scheme, racket

For a school project I have to think about my own encryption method and have to create a program in scheme, which can encrypt and decrypt with that method. I'm quite new to scheme so I need a bit of help.

So I'm working with recursion as you see in my code and as you can see I'm converting the letters into numbers and then I'm moving the letters up as many times as stated in the key. After that I want to convert them back into letters. So my problem is that I want to start with the the key again from the beginning when it's empty, but I don't really know how to do it.

If you want to help me even more, I want to declare a second key, which consists of numbers. That key decides when the first key starts from the beginning again.
I hope you can help me!

```
(define (codieren str ausgabe key1)
  (verschluesseln (umwandeln (string->list str) ausgabe) key1 '()))


(define (umwandeln liste ausgabe)
  (cond
    [(null? liste) ausgabe]
    [else (umwandeln (rest liste)
                   (append ausgabe (list (char->integer (first liste)))))]))

(define (verschluesseln zahlenListe key1 ausgabe)
  (cond
    [(null? zahlenListe) ausgabe]
    [else (verschluesseln (rest zahlenListe) (rest key1)
                          (append ausgabe (list (+ (first zahlenListe) (first key1)))))]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have renamed some variables :)

```
Legend
------
ausgabe        = output
codieren       = encode
verschluesseln = encrypt
umwandeln      = convert
zahlenListe    = numlist
```

... and added some signatures and purpose statements.  [`check-expect`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html)s are tests in Racket's [BSL](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html) (Beginning Student Language).

```
;; String [Listof Character] [Listof Number] -> [Listof Number]
;; converts, then encrypts str by key1
(define (encode str output key1)
  (encrypt (convert (string->list str) output) key1 '()))

(check-expect (encode "abc" '() (list 1 1 1)) (list 98 99 100))

;; [Listof Character] [Listof Character] -> [Listof Character]
;; converts each character in liste to an integer
(define (convert liste output)
  (cond
    [(null? liste) output]
    [else (convert (rest liste)
                   (append output (list (char->integer (first liste)))))]))

;; [Listof Number] [Listof Number] [Listof Number] -> [Listof Number]
;; increments each number in numlist by key1
(define (encrypt numlist key1 output)
  (cond
    [(null? numlist) output]
    [else (encrypt (rest numlist)
                   (rest key1)
                   (append output (list (+ (first numlist) (first key1)))))]))
```

You can build analogous decoder functions (that work backwards):

```
;; [Listof Number] [Listof Number] [Listof Number] -> String
(define (decode code output key1)
  (list->string (convert-back (decrypt code key1 output) '())))

(check-expect (decode (list 98 99 100) '() (list 1 1 1)) "abc")

;; [Listof Number][Listof Number] [Listof Number] -> [Listof Number]
(define (decrypt numlist key1 output)
  (cond
    [(null? numlist) output]
    [else (decrypt (rest numlist)
                   (rest key1)
                   (append output (list (- (first numlist) (first key1)))))]))

(check-expect (decrypt (list 98 99 100) (list 1 1 1) '()) (list 97 98 99))

;; [Listof Number] [Listof Character] -> [Listof Character]
(define (convert-back liste output)
  (cond
    [(null? liste) output]
    [else (convert-back (rest liste)
                        (append output (list (integer->char (first liste)))))]))

(check-expect (convert-back (list 97 98 99) '()) (list #\a #\b #\c))
```

And then test if encoding and decoding something by a key returns the same thing:

```
;; String [Listof Number] -> String
;; encodes and decodes a str by key
(define (encode-decode-identity str key)
  (decode (encode str '() key) '() key))

(check-expect (encode-decode-identity "abc" (list 1 1 1)) "abc")
(check-expect (encode-decode-identity "Gödel" (list 3 0 1 -9 7)) "Gödel")
```

See how key was just used in two two functions.

Note that our encoded message has been a `[Listof Number]`. This can be converted to a string:

```
;; [Listof Number] String -> String
;; converts an encoding `code` to its string form
(define (code-to-string code output)
  (cond [(null? code) output]
        [else (code-to-string (rest code)
                              (string-append output (int->string (first code))))]))

(check-expect (code-to-string (list 98 99 100) "") "bcd")
(check-expect (code-to-string (encode "Church" '() (list 4 2 3 -5 0 9)) "") "Gjxmcq")
```

... which can then be used to encode something multiple times (as you asked):

```
;; Number String [Listof Number] -> String
;; encodes str n times using key
(define (encode-n-times n str key)
  (cond [(= n 0) str]
        [else (encode-n-times (- n 1) (code-to-string (encode str '() key) "") key)]))

(check-expect (encode-n-times 3 "abc" (list 1 1 1)) "def")
```

Instead of "key starts from the beginning again," multiple applications of encode are composed.